# Can someone look at my Java code for numeric diamond pattern using nested loops?

Tags: java, for-loop, nested-loops, jgrasp

I am getting the hang of using nested for loops to make numeric patterns. This code works just fine as long as I do not enter a number above 7. for example, when I put in 7 it looks like this (no spaces):

```
        1

       212

      32123

     4321234

      32123

       212

        1
```

But when I enter 9 it looks like this:

```
                  1

                 212

                32123

               4321234

              543212345

               4321234

                32123
```

What am I doing wrong to make it not finish the diamond?

```
public void displayPatternVI (int lines) 
    {
        System.out.println("\n\tMy Own Pattern to be implemented\n");

        int columns = 1;
        int start = 0;
        int spaces = lines / 2;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++)
        {

            for (int j = 1; j <= spaces; j++)
            {
                System.out.print (" ");
            }


            if(i < lines/2+1)
            {
                start = i;
                spaces = spaces - 1;
            }
            else
            {
                start = (lines + 1 ) - i;
                spaces = spaces + 1;
            }



            for (int j = 1; j <= columns; j++)
            {
                int midColumn = columns / 2 + 1;
                System.out.print(start);
                if (j < midColumn)
                {
                    start--;
                }
                else
                {
                    start++;
                }

            }
            System.out.println();

            if(i<lines/2+1)
            {
                columns = columns + 2;
            }
            else
            {
                columns = columns - 2;
            }



        }




        System.out.println();

    }
```

Comment: What did you discover when you stepped through your code in a debugger?

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth what's that?

Comment: A [debugger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) is a tool that allows you to interactively step through your code line by line, and to investigate the instantaneous values of variables, etc.  Most Java IDEs come with one built-in.  Now would be an excellent time to learn how to use one, as they're extremely useful for diagnosing bugs in code!

Comment: @OliCharlesworth oh. I use JGrasp. does that have a debugger or is there a particular IDE I should download?

Comment: yes, its a homework :)

Comment: @KelliDavis: I've never used JGrasp, but apparently it includes a debugger: http://www.jgrasp.org/tutorials187/06_Debugger.pdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about changing `<= 7` to `<= 9` (or most likely a variable holding the input number)

Change :

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++)
```

to

```
for (int i = 1; i <= lines; i++)
```

Comment: thank you very much!! Now I feel foolish.

Comment: I am having a problem making this work with even numbers.

Comment: never mind. when I change it to i <= lines + 1 it works with even numbers just fine